# SDL not render to the full window after set window size

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Here is the steps I use SDL to load image.

1. create window and render with default size, e.g `100x100`
2. create texture from image with `IMG_LoadTexture`
3. Query texture info and get texture dimension, e.g `800x600`, then use `SDL_SetWindowSize` to resize to the required size
4. perform render

The result is SDL only render to the `100x100` region when the window created, the other part is not render.

How can I make SDL render to full window after `SDL_SetWindowSize`?

Below is my sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
SDL_Window* sdlWindow;
SDL_Renderer* sdlRenderer;
SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(100, 100, 0, &sdlWindow, &sdlRenderer);

IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_JPG);

SDL_Texture* sdlTexture = IMG_LoadTexture(sdlRenderer, "test-wallpaper-800x600.jpg");

Uint32 format;
int access, w, h;
if (SDL_QueryTexture(sdlTexture, &format, &access, &w, &h) == 0) {
    SDL_SetWindowSize(sdlWindow, w, h);
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "linear");
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(sdlRenderer, w, h);
}

SDL_RenderClear(sdlRenderer);
SDL_RenderCopy(sdlRenderer, sdlTexture, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(sdlRenderer);

SDL_Event sdlEvent;
while (SDL_WaitEvent(&sdlEvent)) {
    if (sdlEvent.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT
        && sdlEvent.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE) {
        break;
    }
    if (sdlEvent.type == SDL_KEYDOWN
            && sdlEvent.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
        break;
    }
}

SDL_DestroyRenderer(sdlRenderer);
SDL_DestroyWindow(sdlWindow);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see an updated rendering because you only render it once before the frame loop. To solve this problem, move the rendering into the frame loop, like so:

```
SDL_Event sdlEvent;
while (SDL_WaitEvent(&sdlEvent))
{
    if (sdlEvent.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT
        && sdlEvent.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE) {
        break;
    }
    if (sdlEvent.type == SDL_KEYDOWN
            && sdlEvent.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
        break;
    }

    // Render here
    SDL_RenderClear(sdlRenderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(sdlRenderer, sdlTexture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(sdlRenderer);
}
```